# Bootstrap Modal not working any more after routing

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, url-routing, altorouter

I just included some routing in my project, using **`AltoRouter`**. I am using relatively simple routing, something like:

```
$router->map('GET','/room/[*:chatid]','chat.php','chat');
```

Now on the **`chat.php`**, I have a modal. This modal works perfectly fine before including the routing. But now, there is another problems with the modal.

- **the modal is always there as a normal div underneath the rest of the
  page**
- **it is never shown as a modal at all, not even in the moment it should
  be shown**

Following is the code for the modal.

```
<div id="namePopup" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Username festlegen</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content">
            Bitte einen Namen für den Chat festlegen:<br/>
            <input id="chatRoomName"/>
            <button id="submitChatRoomName">Name festlegen</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then, when navigating to the page, I just check for a set cookie. If it is not set I want to open the modal:

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem("username") === null){
     window.location.href="#namePopup";
}
```

The JS seems to be working fine, as **`#namePopup`** is correctly added to the URL when needed. But I guess, the router can not use this, although I do not understand, why it is always shown instead then.

Can anybody help me figure out the problem or help me creating a route for opening the modal, if that's needed?